# R: Restrict OLS Coefficients

Tags: r, least-squares

i am currently setting up a portfolio on the Basis of cointegrating relationships for an assignment at uni. Therefore, I need to restrict my OLS coeffients, so that the total sum of coefficients is equal to 1. The unrestricted OLS estimation is given by:
`lm(mran_port[,1] ~ mran_port[,2:draws])`

where the dependent variable is the corresponding index. The explanatory variables are set up dynamically, so that the number of regressors depends on the value of draws. I already tried a reparamererization, but this does not give sufficient results. Is there a suitable function in R?

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I do not think you need that restriction for cointegrarion....but in the case you wanted it you just need to write your own likelihood function and optimize it with optim

Answer (score 3):

You can easily restrict OLS coefficients in R.  What I normally try and do is write my own likelihood function and optimize it with optim. In your case I would do the following:

```
w.fun=function(r){ #invertible function from R^(n-1) to unit n weight space (where coef's sum to 1)
  b=exp(c(0,r));
  b/sum(b)
} 

rest.reg=function(Y,X){ #restricted regression function
  n=ncol(X);
  start.init=rep(0,n-1) #loose one dimention from restirction

  nll=function(b) #negative log likelihood function Y~X
  {
    beta=w.fun(b); #restrict beta's to sum to 1
    resid=Y-X%*%beta;

    -sum(dnorm(resid,sd=sqrt(mean(resid^2)),log=TRUE)) ##output neg. log likelihood
  }
  return(optim(start.init,nll,method="BFGS",hessian=TRUE))
}
# random example
X=cbind(1,matrix(rnorm(1e3),ncol=10))

Y=rnorm(1e2)

m1=rest.reg(Y,X)
##coeficients
coef=w.fun(m1$par)
print(round(coef,3))
sum(coef)
```

the optim function optimizes the log-likelihood over the real-space and the parameters are transformed inside the log-likelihood to sum to 1 (I do this to make the function easier to optimize).  In the case of OLS, maximizing the log-likelihood (minimizing the negative log likelihood) is synonymous with minimizing mean squared error.

Getting standard errors for the coefficients is a little tricky.  There are two basic ways to do it.  Either (1) apply the Delta method to the Hessian that is returned by rest.reg or (2) use a bootstrap.  I was lazy so I didn't do either of those.  The bootstrap is usually preferred if you have a lot of data, otherwise you could use the delta method.

In either case, I am not so sure you need this restriction for finding a cointigration vector.  Since in a regression framework you are already effectively restricting the coefficient on the dependent to 1, you are guaranteed a unique solution if one exists...but maybe I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas so far. I do not want to use an optimization in the general (standard) case. I am following Alexander(1999), where firstly an OLS estimation is performened and then in the case of cointegration the relationship is extracted and used as weight for the exact portfolio composition. Thus, if they are standardized to sum up to 1, the corresponding beta coeffient is the weight in the Portfolio, e.g: `beta_1 = -0,2, beta2 = 0,4 , beta3 = 0,8`. Then 20 % of the Portfolios value is short in stock 1 and 40 % and 80 % in stock 2 and 3 respectively. Thus the index - the dependend

Comment: @user98715. That's fine.  I think we are thinking about different kinds of cointegration.  However the function I gave you will not let you short....for that replace b=exp (c (0,r)) with b=c (1,r);  in the w.fun.